# change color of list elements according to condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have two tables :

Table 1 (overall Score )
[image: overall]

Table 2 (weekly score )
[image: weekly]

I have a leaderboard where I am echoing the overall score value **from Table 1** :

[image: lb]

**Problem :** What I am trying to do here is that whoever scores "-10" in table 2 (weekly score) , I want to alert the user by highlighting the color of their box in the leaderboard ,which is yellow now, to red.

current css involved :

```
li mark div {
    display: block;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #eebb55;
    border-radius: 7pt;
    background: grey;
}
```

Php involved to display the list.This is for "overall" (right tab in leader board) .Similar exist for weekly too .

```
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
    <div class="leaderboard">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <mark>
                    <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
                        echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";
                    } ?>
                </mark>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Queries passed to retrieve info from both the tables :

**1.query 1** - to find out all the employees with a score of -10.

```
$q200 = " select *
  from Table2
  where  WeekNumber = 'week1' and pointsRewarded = '-10';";
  $stmt200=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q200);
  if($stmt200==false)
  {
  echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
  }
```

**query 2- to retrieve from table 1 all the employees :**

```
$q20 = "select *
  from EmployeeTable
  order by Total_points_Rewarded desc";
  $stmt20=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q20);
  if($stmt20==false)
  {
  echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
  }
```

**Code that I tried with :**

```
<?php while( $toprow20 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt20) ) {

echo  "<div class='parent-divv'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow20['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow20['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow20['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

}?>
<?php if ($toprow20['EmployeeID'] == $toprow200['EmployeeID'] ) ?>{
  <style>
  .parent-divv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
  </style>
}
```

**The code above changes all color to red.I want only matching names/ID in both queries to be red.rest remain as it is. 
I am using PHP,Please suggest me a way to do it.God bless.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To highlight the data acording to age with specific color in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997134/to-highlight-the-data-acording-to-age-with-specific-color-in-php)

Comment: be sure to use if else contition not a simple if

Comment: Make a class for every style and assign the classes to the appropriate element(s).

Comment: i m not sure to understand the question, you want to know wich data is in both array ?

Comment: @MandarSant how is that a duplicate ? Its a different one.U have an answer there,Plz help me here too.I would be grateful.

Comment: @chris85 i believe that wont be necessary.I just want those names in result of bot queries to change to red in the echoed list.

Comment: You assign all divs the same class then tell that class to have a red border...

Comment: @chris85 i tried somehing similar.but no luck. code : .parent-div.name {
  <?php if ($toprow20['EmployeeName'] == $toprow200['EmployeeName'] ) ?>{
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
  </style>
}

Comment: They all get that class though. Only give the ones that need it that class.

Comment: @liza is the question still open/unsolved? *curious*

Comment: yeah its unsolved . @Fred-ii-

Comment: @liza *Hm...*, ok. Well this statement `and pointsRewarded = '-10'` am unsure of, as it may be interpreted as a string. If this is an sql issue, then try `and pointsRewarded = -10`. Btw, what is the column type for `points`? Plus, where did you define `$toprow200`? You sure you didn't mean `$toprow20` also? If it's a typo, then error reporting would have told you about an undefined variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have defined $toprow20 and $toprow200 both before using them.m using float for pointsRewarded.I dont think its taking as string coz i have used similar ways in other queries too.I believe something is wrong with the PHP.

Comment: @liza if it's a php issue, see if error reporting picks up on anything http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and look at your console as well as checking for errors on the query. Look at your html source also, it's just as good a tool, as will `var_dump()`.

Comment: It wont display anything coz if you look at my above code I tried,its correct.Its just the logic that I am unable to code.In the above code,I am making all borders red,which is not what I want. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Don't give them all the same class.

Comment: @liza you could use a ternary operator for this. However, I notice `<div class='parent-div'>` and `.parent-divv` - are those related or separate? is `class='parent-div'` not suppose to be `class='parent-divv'`? TBH, I don't know what else to do. You also tagged as javascript, but no code for it, is it relevant? Is it for a popup box?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have not tagged any javascript here.Also "parent-div" is same.i just tried to give a different class.

Comment: @liza Funny; look under your question; it holds both "javascript" and "jquery" tags *lol* If you didn't include them, "goblins"? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have written two queries above.Both displays weekly and overall scores respectively.In the weekly query the person who has score of -10,I want that employee's box in leader board to turn red.

Comment: also, right now ,I echo the result from "overall score" query into the above leader board (pz see pic).I want the common names in both the queries to turn red in the leaderboard.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the javascript  - are you talking about the other question bdw.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i got it.the tags.i just thought someone might have come acrss something similar during dev. Anyways,i tried explaining u the issues.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41478923/1011527 (sock puppet alert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Join the the queries into one

```
select EmployeeTable.*,Table2.pointsRewarded as `weeklyDelta`
from EmployeeTable join Table2 on EmployeeTable.EmployeeID = Table2.EmployeeID
where Table2.WeekNumber = 'week1'
order by Total_points_Rewarded desc
```

2) Then give the employees with negative deltas a special class

```
<?php  
while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
    echo  "<div class='parent-div" .
        ($toprow2['weeklyDelta'] <= -10 ? " dropped" : "") .
        "'><span class='rank'>" .
        $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . 
        $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . 
        $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";
} ?>
```

3) give those employees a style

```
.parent-div.dropped { color:red }
```

Comment: thanks for the input.Now ,I dont want to add an another attribute in the table as whatever I need is already available from both the queries.I just want to match their ID/name from the data retrived from both the queries and if same name exist change color to red.

Comment: also I dont want to echo score 0f -10 employees anywhere.I just want their names to turn red if their names are in the list.

Comment: This isn't adding an attribute to the table, just the query results. It is also more efficiant as you are only hitting the DB once with all the data you need, instead of twice. Also it isn't echoing the -10, just a new class name if they are -10.

Comment: using ur above query would create anew column with name "`weeklyDelta` in employee table.I believe your solution is pretty near to what I am trying.Its just that I dont want a new column.The tables in my DB contains large amount of data ,not just these four entries I have mentioned above.Its just to explain you guys.

Comment: It adds nothing to the table, just in the results coming back. If you do have massive amounts of data then this is the most efficient way. otherwise you'd need to cycle through each entry in query 2 for each entry in query 1 to see if they match up. Combining the queries into one makes the DB do that work for you.

Comment: is there a way, such that if there are common names from both the queries,then box turn red for that employee.because i am using query2 results to echo in the above leaderboard.(plz see above pic)

Comment: you'd need to cycle through query 1 for each entry in query 2 to find a potential match, then add a class (or style attribute) to turn the box red.

the above query removes the need for query 1, as it combines the information into one data set.

     `($toprow2['weeklyDelta'] <= -10 ? " dropped" : "")`

this ternary statement is a one line "if ... else .." statement that adds "dropped" if weekly Delta is -10 or nothing if it isn't

Comment: ($toprow2['weeklyDelta'] <= -10 ? " dropped" : "") .
        "'><span class='rank'>" . ----- this is echoing results which I dont want to echo.

Comment: Moreover, its not an optimal solution.I can upvote but not accept.Thanks a lot for trying.God bless.

Comment: `"<div class='parent-div" .
        ($toprow2['weeklyDelta'] <= -10 ? " dropped" : "") .
        "'><span class='rank'>"` converts to `<div class="parent-div dropped"><span class="rank">` if the employee is -10 or `<div class="parent-div"><span class="rank">` if they are not. You can then style `.dropped { color: red }` nothing (other than the extra class) is changed.

Comment: This works.Sorry I misunderstood some part of the code.Thanks a lot for all the help.God bless.